# Сессия PHP с привязкой

Tags: php, сессия

Как сделать так,что бы кнопка если человек не авторизован на сайте перекидывала на форму регистрации, а если авторизован то на другую страницу? Монжно просто указать источник, или название самого процесса, в таком случае могу сам поискать ответ

Comment: Ответ в заголовке вопроса - "сессия PHP"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от того, активна ли сессия, посылать соответствующий header. Т.е. как-то так...

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location: form.php");
} else {
    header("Location: otherpage.php");
}

?>
```

Почитать про сессии можно в том числе и [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/refs.basic.session.php)

Comment: Все файлы которые нуждаются в сессии должны быть в формате PHP, и в начале я открываю или продолжаю уже начатую сессию, после чего уже задаю условие, верно?

Comment: Скрипт, обрабатывающий данные формы (указаный в атрибуте `action`) запускает сессию с помощью `session_start()` и регистрирует переменную через `$_SESSION`. Другой скрипт (который выше) в зависимости от условия делает само перенаправление...